# Почему в виртуальной машине изначально не установлены гостевые дополнения?

Tags: безопасность, виртуальная-машина

Почему в виртуальной машине изначально не установлены гостевые дополнения ?

И есть ли курсы по правильному пользованию виртуальных машин, где сравнивают ужасно неудобную, но безопасную работу и удобную, но опасную для главного хоста?

Мне интересно анализировать вирусы и как они работают, но при этом нет желания портить основной хост.

Речь о virtual box.

В vmware развернуть на полный экран можно по умолчанию.

Comment: Изначально в среднестатистической виртуальной машине не установлено вообще ничего, всё устанавливаете лично вы. Что установите — то и будет. С дополнениями или без — зависит только от вас.

Comment: Если же в виртуальной машине, о которой вы говорите в вопросе, изначально что-то всё-таки есть, то расскажите подробнее, о чём речь

Comment: "Почему в виртуальной машине изначально не установлены гостевые дополнения ?" Потому что у них, в отличие от производителей ноутов, кишка тонка купить ТАКУЮ лицензию Windows. И\или просто не хотят. (Если бы хотели, поставили бы пиратскую и придумали как выкручиваться) А нет винды - нет и предустановленного софта.

Comment: Кроме виртуальных машин, можно купить VPS с Windows Server и использовать его не как сервер, а как второй комп с виндой - подключаться по RDP (удаленный рабочий стол). Хотя, есть и свои минусы - нет видеокарты (поэтому игры не пойдут); при BSoD вы не получите информации синего экрана, также и при сильной нагрузке на ЦП просто пропадет связь.

Comment: @SmInc (оффтоп) а если хотить на VPS по предоставляемому хостингом VNC, то даже BIOS отлично виден :)

Comment: Хотя вообще, подозреваю, изучение вирусни на VPS скорее всего будет нарушать правила хостинга, на котором он находится

Comment: @andreymal Антивирус держать мы не обязаны (не встречал, чтобы где-то требовалось), бывают свои механизмы типа детекта файлов с именем "ddos", но это совсем что–то странное, и то не везде.

Comment: Т.е изначально невозможно перетаскивать файлы мышкой с хоста на виртуальную машину и разворачивать экран на все 100%, потому что нет операционной системы в ней ? Значит гостевые дополнения зависят от операционной системы  (если linux - ставим одни гостевые дополнения, иначе - другие гостевые дополнения) Так @andreymal ?

Comment: Совершенно верно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Из комментариев в ответы. Прошу исправить или написать свой **ответ**, если есть что добавить.*

Изначально невозможно перетаскивать файлы мышкой с хоста на виртуальную машину и разворачивать экран на все 100%, потому что в виртуальной машине нет операционной системы. Отсюда получается что гостевые дополнения **зависят** от операционной системы , т.е **если** linux - ставим одни гостевые дополнения, **иначе** - другие гостевые дополнения.